# reshape and aggregate datatable

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, reshape, tidyr

I asked a very similar question and because I haven't quite gotten a handle on tidyr or reshape I have to ask another question. I have a datatable containing repeat id values (see below):

```
id  Product NI  
1   Direct Auto 15  
2   Direct Auto 15  
3   Direct Auto 15  
4   Direct Auto 15  
5   Direct Auto 15  
6   Direct Auto 15  
6   Mortgage    50  
9   Direct Auto 15  
10  Direct Auto 15  
11  Direct Auto 15  
12  Direct Auto 15  
13  Direct Auto 15  
14  Direct Auto 15  
15  Direct Auto 15  
16  Direct Auto 15  
1   Mortgage    50  
5   Personal    110  
19  Direct Auto 15  
20  Direct Auto 15  
1   Direct Auto 15
```

I would like the id aggregated to one row, the Product column to be 'spread' so that the values become variables, another variable containing the aggregated count of each Product by id, and the NI to be summed for each of the product groups by ID. So see example below:

```
id  DirectAuto  DA_NI   Mortgage    Mortgage_NI Personal    P_NI  
1   2   30  1   50  NA  NA  
2   1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
3   1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
4   1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
5   1   15  NA  NA  1   110  
6   1   15  1   50  NA  NA  
9   1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
11  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
12  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
13  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
14  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
15  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
16  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
19  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA  
20  1   15  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

For example, id 1 has 2 Direct Auto, so his DA_NI is 30 and he has 1 Mortgage so his NI is Mortgage_NI = 50.

So, basically make a 'wider' datatable.  I'm still reading and practicing tidyr and reshape, but in the mean-time maybe someone can help.
Here is some of my starting code:

```
df[, .(tot = .N, NI = sum(NI)), by = c("id","Product")]
```

Afterwards, using some tidyr & reshape commands I can't seem to get the final output I want.

Comment: Try formatting your code http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Fyi, the syntax in your last line of code only works for the data.table package, which has its own tag.

Comment: It would really help if you would include code to create your sample data so people can try solutions without having to labor over that part.

Comment: yes, I am using a datatable

Comment: ulfelder...I just wrote the sample data in Excel and copied it in. Please let me know what is the preferred method. tu

Comment: The preferred method uses R's `dput` command. You'll have to move your data from excel into R before starting, so you might as well do that first. Here's a guide for `dput` and asking R questions generally: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259

Comment: my data is in R. I just put a sample in Excel to post on the board. TU I'll take a look at this.

Comment: FYI, the package (and tag) is `data.table`, not `datatable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`data.table v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) has more nicer features for *melting* and *casting*. Using `dcast` from the devel version:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5
dcast(dt, id ~ Product, fun.agg = list(sum, length), value.var="NI", fill=NA)
```

I think this is what you're looking for. You can checkout the *new HTML vignettes* [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Rename the columns to your liking.

Comment: I followed the steps and downloaded the eval version but received this error: Error in FUN(X[[7L]], ...) : could not find function ".fun"......also, will this give me the sum of NI and count of Product by ID, I'm trying to visualize this in your code

Comment: You're running `reshape2::dcast`, whereas this requires `data.table::dcast`.

Comment: that was great. Much less writing to accomplish my results...appreciate the mulitple value.r and value.var functionality that has been added.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to do this. It can be done using `tidyr` and `dplyr` though it goes against Hadley Wickgam's tidy data principles.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id, Product) %>%
  summarise(NI = sum(NI), n = n()) %>%
  gather(variable, value, n, NI) %>%
  mutate(
    col_name = ifelse(variable == "n",
      as.character(Product),
      paste(Product, variable, sep = "_"))
  ) %>%
  select(-c(Product, variable)) %>%
  spread(col_name, value)
```

Comment: I get this error message:  Error in n() : This function should not be called directly.   Also, I think first(NI) should be sum, no?

Comment: I suspect you have both `plyr` and `dplyr` loaded. Try replacing `summarise` with `dplyr::summarise` or executing `detach("package:plyr")` first.

Comment: And yes, it should have been `sum`. I misread what you wanted.